# Dependency problem

Tags: roboearth

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

This is probably a trivial question, but for the love of god I am not able to find a solution. I am running ros-electric on a Ubuntu 64-bit 11.04 machine. I have a ros_external folder in my home directory where I install external ros packages and stack that I use for my projects. I have added this path to my ROS_PACKAGE_PATH. I am trying to create a package for object detection with Kinect. I am using the roboearth stack for detecting the objects. The roboearth stack is installed in the ros_external, specifically the stack.xml file is located in ~/ros_external/stacks/roboearth. I am able to reach this using the roscd roboearth command, which I thought meant that ROS was able to find this stack. However, when I try to create a package listing roboearth as a dependency, I get an error that dependency [roboearth] cannot be found.

roboearth is a stack and not a package, I wonder if that matters. Any help is appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12039/dependency-problem/) by [Sudarshan](https://answers.ros.org/users/291/sudarshan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 113 on 2011-11-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, indeed that is the problem. If you package requires code from a certain package in roboearth then you need to depend on that specific package. So you need to fill in your dependencies as packages. The stack containing your package, on the other hand, will then depend on the roboearth stack (stack depends on stacks, package depends on packages).

---

Originally posted by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) with karma: 5904 on 2011-11-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2011-11-22**:
No. @AHornung is right: stack dependencies are for installation; package dependencies are for build resolution. You need both.

**Comment by [Sudarshan](https://answers.ros.org/users/291/sudarshan/) on 2011-11-22**:
I might end up having my package depending on all the packages provided by roboearth. So would it be easier that I build a stack with one package and the stack depends on roboearth stack?